# Python's smtplib module violating Gmail's terms of use

Tags: python, email, gmail, policy, smtplib

**How can I avoid violating Gmail's terms of use when using Python's `smtplib`?**

I would like to send internal emails using Python. After 2 days of fighting with the Gmail API, I gave up. Then I found the `smtplib` module, which looked simple and promising.

Following the example [here](https://www.mkyong.com/python/how-do-send-email-in-python-via-smtplib/), I wrote this small block of Python code:

```
import smtplib

# Details of where to send FROM
emailUser     = 'an.account.I.made.just.for this.test@gmail.com'
emailPassword = 'password123'

# Send the following message to an address...
message       = '[ I am email content ]'
toAddress     = 'test.victim@gmail.com'

# Define the HEADER (to, from, and subject)
header = """
  To: %s
  From: %s
  Subject: Python SMTPLIB Test
"""
header = header % (toAddress, emailUser)

# [ Don't know what this does ]
smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com",587)
smtpserver.ehlo()
smtpserver.starttls()
smtpserver.ehlo

# Use User/Password credentials to send email
smtpserver.login(emailUser, emailPassword)
smtpserver.sendmail(emailUser, toAddress, message)

smtpserver.close()
```

I executed this script. It looks like Google's algorithms must have interpreted this as having been sent with bad intentions, and promptly closed my account! Which is fair enough, as I'm sure `smtplib` can be abused quite readily. However, I have honest intentions, but I do not know how to get around this issue: **how can I avoid violating Gmail's terms of use when using Python's `smtplib`?**

Answer (score 1):

It could be because you are indiscriminately making connections with EHLO, you should be using HELO.

If the server supports EHLO, the client can use EHLO instead of HELO as its first request.
On the other hand, if the server does not support EHLO, and the client sends EHLO, the server will reject EHLO. The client then has to fall back to HELO.

There are a few servers that disconnect when they see EHLO. If the client finds that neither EHLO nor HELO was accepted, for example because the connection was closed, then it has to make a new connection and start with HELO.